# All applications on a Weblogic server

Tags: java, web-applications, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, wlst

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find name of all application running on a WebLogic server through a java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081341/find-name-of-all-application-running-on-a-weblogic-server-through-a-java-web-app)

I am writing a java web application
that needs to know the name of all applications running on the same
server on which the application will be deployed on.

Maybe I can combine use of WLST with java?

any ideas?

Thanks,
Shehryar Farooq

Answer (score 0):

> JMX is the answer to the question. Please check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081341/find-name-of-all-application-running-on-a-weblogic-server-through-a-java-web-app)